# Debugging missing observation in spring-graphql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-graphql

What is the proper approach in determining the missing observations (`graphql.request`, `graphql.datafetcher`) by spring-graphql that is supported out-of-the-box (https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.2.2/reference/html/#observability)?

These observations previously existed, but somehow, after a few changes, unrelated to any configuration, seem to be missing.

```java
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestGraphQL {
  @QueryMapping
  public String hello(@Argument String id) {
    return "Hello World!" + id;
  }
}
```

I tried setting the same query on a sample repository and the observations are indeed created. Something seems to be wrong with the actual repository, but hard to pinpoint where...

I don't have any ObservationFilter to skip it as well.

I tried setting the logs to DEBUG level but still couldn't have an idea what's going wrong.

Comment: It is possible that some auto-configuration does not apply. Can you put « debug=true » in your application.properties file and copy/paste here the auto-configuration report?